# WatchKit without ARC causes crash when dealloc

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, watchkit, watchos-2, dealloc

The watch app I am developing is not using ARC. And so I releases all the properties of objects in each interface in `dealloc` as below.

```
-(void)dealloc {

  [obj1 release];
  [obj2 release];
   ...
  [super dealloc];
}
```

This causes crash when i close the interface (for example to go back to main interface). Why is this so?

Comment: *The watch app I am developing is not using ARC.* Because you haven't adopted ARC, you're making it harder on yourself by a) trying to manually reference count (which will lead to more crashes or leaks), instead of letting the tools automatically do it for you, and b) writing obsolete code now which would have to be ported in the future.

Comment: I don't have a choice, the current project that the watch app going to be attached does not have ARC.

Comment: Just because an existing iOS app didn't use ARC, it doesn't mean a new watch app also can't use ARC. Target settings *can* override project settings. This will allow your watch app to be compiled with ARC support, while your iOS app can continue to not use ARC until you upgrade it.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I can try it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retains and releases need to be balanced in the context of your class. Probably you didn't retain when you assigned to one of those instance variables, and thus it's an over-release. You can try enabling zombies to catch the message to a deallocated instance if that's the case.